# Отступ у border

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">
#id a {
 border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
</style>
```

Как бордер отделить от текста примерно на 5px?

http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1355701600-clip-193b.png если не понятно. Бордер будто прилип к тексту.

Comment: @ModaL, не создавайте, пожалуйста, нежелательные (лишние) метки!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
padding-bottom: 5px;
```

не?...

Comment: @knes, мне аж стыдно стало :D

Comment: высыпаться надо. Мне с недосыпу и не такое бывает.

Comment: в a:hover padding-bottom: 5px; не работает((

Answer (score -1):

```
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

и всё должно работать.